# Detecting when VS debugger is stopped at a breakpoint?

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-studio-2015, breakpoints, managed

In managed `.NET` debugging with **Visual Studio 2017**, is there any way to detect whether your code is being called by the debugger context, i.e. when stopped at a breakpoint?

I believe this is known as the *[func-eval](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2005/11/15/rules-of-funceval/)* context (more [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2005/03/23/func-eval-is-evil/)), and it happens when you stop a breakpoint and the debugger automatically calls your code in order to display `ToString()` results (if enabled) on property values in the *Locals*, *Autos*, *Watch*, etc. windows, and also to evaluate arbitrary functions you enter while stopped.

Note that I'm aware of [Debugger.IsAttached](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached), but this is not the same; it indicates if the process is being debugged, regardless of whether the debugger is stopped or running at the time of the call. This question seeks a more specific case: `Debugger.IsAttached` must be `true`, but that's not enough because it doesn't say whether you're in the debugger's *func-eval* context.

Since this should be just a simple global `bool` value somewhere, I'm hoping the solution doesn't involve `COM` calls (i.e. to [ICorDebugAppDomain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/debugging/icordebugappdomain-interface)).

Comment: What I know is that we often use the Conditional Breakpoint to check that whether the VS debugger is stopped at a breakpoint: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2014/10/06/new-breakpoint-configuration-experience-in-visual-studio-2015/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The code can't tell if it's being invoked by a func-eval. In general, we don't really want code behaving differently under a debugger vs. normally... that leads to horribly hard problems to debug.

If you're trying to avoid func-evals, you could use the DebuggerDisplay attribute.
You could use Debugger.NotifyOfCrossThreadDependency() to signal the debugger to abort a func-eval. (see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/eliofek/2012/12/12/why-do-we-get-the-function-evaluation-requires-all-threads-to-run/ for more details)

Comment: Thanks for this info. Not sure the justification that 'providing such detection would "lead to horribly hard problems to debug" (for ***debugger*** developers, presumably)' is warranted, since the lone use case here is for the ***application*** developer to work around *debugger* bugs! For example, the myriad problems debugging value-type designs/scenarios that are inherently ruined by boxing and/or remoting (especially since for these, `DebuggerTypeProxy` only makes matters worse).

Comment: I was talking about *Application* developers. If the app behaves differently when run under the debugger, it can be harder for the application developer to debug a production issue. We called these "heisenbugs".

Comment: Ah, I see; thanks for the clarification, and I certainly agree with that consensus. But then the point remains from my comment above; namely that the lack of an easy way to detect *func-eval* makes it hard for the app developer to work around *bona-fide*, legitimate, and well-understood debugger issues or limitations. Ironically (or perversely), the lack of a simple indicator here may unnecessarily cause added complexity and sprawl to the requisite eventual app-level debugger workarounds, making it *harder to keep such contamination entirely out* of the production build.

Comment: Func-eval only happens under a debugger - so it's not going to be an issue for a production server. 
And even when it does happen, there are best-practices to avoid func-evals. IE, use DebuggerDisplay.

Comment: Yes, clearly *func-eval* only happens under a debugger, but I allude to debugger-workaround code that exists in the app. Sure, debugger- and/or debugging-specific code can be `#if`'d out of the app or skipped at runtime, or separated to reduce clutter, etc. But *by your own "heisenbug" principle*, all such code should be eliminated--or at least kept to a minimum--and the best way to do exactly that--**given a situation which requires *func-eval* detection**--is to expose it in the most trivial/simple way possible--so the app won't bloat with debug "heisencode" by trying to fetch it from COM.

Comment: My use case is "don't throw a timeout exception if I'm in the middle of debugging something else"...